# Backbone Start twice

Tags: backbone.js

I started a simple Backbone app, but my start function run twice. What did I wrong?

```
 var ActivityApp = new (Backbone.View.extend({
    Models: {},
    Views: {},
    Collections: {},
    start: function() {
      console.log('ad');
    }   }))({el: document.body});

$(function(){ ActivityApp.start(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works fine.. http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/5zzzchpq/

You wrote it in a strange way though, this makes more sense and is the "backbone way":

```
var ActivityApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      console.log('initialize');
    }
});

new ActivityApp({
    el: document.body
});
```